# Views Slideshow only shows one static image and doesn't cycle in IE8

Tags: views, 6, javascript

I have a slideshow that runs through numerous images on the homepage of a site. The slideshow works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox, but simply shows a static image in IE8. On IE8, a Javascript error is returned as follows:

> Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
>
> Line: 160
>
> Char: 5
>
> Code: 0
>
> URI: /sites/all/modules/views_slideshow/contrib/views_slideshow_singleframe/views_slideshow.js

The Drupal settings JS is as follows:

```
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, { "basePath": "/", "admin_menu": { "margin_top": 1 },
"admin_menu_dropdown": { "key": "`", "default": 1 }, "colorbox": { "transition": 
"elastic", "speed": 350, "opacity": "0.85", "slideshow": false, "slideshowAuto": 
false, "slideshowSpeed": 2500, "slideshowStart": "", "slideshowStop": "", "current": 
"{current} of {total}", "previous": "« Prev", "next": "Next »", "close": "Close", 
"overlayClose": true, "maxWidth": "100%", "maxHeight": "100%" }, "CTools": { 
"pageId": "page-4d858fb47100047beb7ca4246959a972" }, "extlink": { "extTarget": 
"_blank", "extClass": "ext", "extSubdomains": 1, "extExclude": "", "extInclude": "",
 "extAlert": 0, "extAlertText": "This link will take you to an external web site. We 
are not responsible for their content.", "mailtoClass": "mailto" }, 
"viewsSlideshowSingleFrame": { "#views_slideshow_singleframe_main_main_panel-block_1": { 
"num_divs": 7, "id_prefix": "#views_slideshow_singleframe_main_", 
"div_prefix": "#views_slideshow_singleframe_div_", "vss_id": "main_panel-block_1"
, "timeout": "5000", "sort": 1, "effect": "fade", "speed": "700", "start_paused": 
null, "delay": "0", "fixed_height": "1", "random": "0", "pause": "2", 
"pause_on_click": "0", "pause_when_hidden": 0, "pause_when_hidden_type": "full", 
"amount_allowed_visible": "", "remember_slide": 0, "remember_slide_days": 1, 
"controls": "0", "items_per_slide": 1, "pager": "0", "pager_type": "Numbered", 
"pager_hover": "1", "pager_click_to_page": 0, "image_count": "0", "nowrap": "0", 
"sync": "1", "advanced": "", "ie": { "cleartype": "true", "cleartypenobg": "false" } 
} } });
//--><!]]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this was caused by something in the template.  The developer had called the JQuery library from the page.tpl file when it was already being called by core, so it caused the error in IE.  See [this page on drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/620184) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try turn off some modules and check it then. I have problem with devel module. After turn it off my   views slideshow started to work.

Comment: I already figured it out, see the accepted answer.